# Is this the proper way to use the timeit module?

Tags: python, performance, timeit

I have the following code and results.

Tests 1 and 2 are identical (at least I think they are) but they always take a different amount of time to run.

My questions are:

1. Am I using `timeit()` correctly?
2. Do milliseconds matter when evaluating one syntax vs another?
3. If I am not doing anything wrong, why the difference?
4. Is `timeit` the correct way to test performance or are there better ways?

Code:

```
import timeit

def test1(a="String1", b="String2", c="String3",
          d="I took a heavenly ride through our silence "):
    r = a + b + c + d

def test2(e="String1", f="String2", g="String3",
          h="I took a heavenly ride through our silence "):
    s = e + f + g + h

def test3(e="String1", f="String2", g="String3",
          h="I took a heavenly ride through our silence "):
    t = e.join([f,g,h])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    reps = 10000000

    print("Test 1")
    print(timeit.timeit("test1()", number=reps,
                        setup="from __main__ import test1"))
    print("Test 2")
    print(timeit.timeit("test2()", number=reps,
                        setup="from __main__ import test2"))
    print("Test 3")
    print(timeit.timeit("test3()", number=reps,
                        setup="from __main__ import test3"))

    print(" ")
    print(" ")

    print("Test 2")
    print(timeit.timeit("test2()", number=reps,
                        setup="from __main__ import test2"))
    print("Test 1")
    print(timeit.timeit("test1()", number=reps,
                        setup="from __main__ import test1"))
    print("Test 3")
    print(timeit.timeit("test3()", number=reps,
                        setup="from __main__ import test3"))
```

Results:

```
Test 1
3.46861560261924
Test 2
3.4760945739099185
Test 3
6.51532737832723


Test 2
3.475778266347378
Test 1
3.465791808905923
Test 3
6.493744207694682
```

Comment: Are you talking about the tiny difference between 3.47... and 3.46...? I'd guess that's just random noise. It's about a difference of less than 0.3%. If it was 3% it might be worth investigating, but I'd expect you to have error much larger than that difference just from the other stuff running on your system at the same time you're doing the test.

Comment: Blckknght, yes i was talking about the 3.47 and 3.46... thanks for the reply...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation [link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html).

- Processes running on the system may interfere with the timing as
  timeit measures clock time, not CPU time.
- By default, `timeit()` temporarily turns off garbage collection during the timing. The advantage of this approach is that it makes independent timings more comparable. This disadvantage is that GC may be an important component of the performance of the function being measured.

To call `timeit()` repeatedly,

`def test():
    L = []
    for i in range(10):
        L.append(i)`

`if __name__ == '__main__':
    import timeit
    print(timeit.repeat("test()", setup="from __main__ import test"))`